# Spark showing stage progress twice

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Not sure if this is an obvious question, but I noticed that everytime Spark is executing an action, e.g. load from files or select from dataframe, the progress shown as `Stage ======>` is repeated twice.

It happens throghout my script so it's not a specific code that I can show. I am also not sure how to check it some other way to be sure whether it actually is executing twice, or it's just showing.

Does anyone know if this is a problem, or where I can check to be sure?

Comment: if you have [Spark’s history server](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) running, you can view [stages](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui-stages.html) from [spark-webui](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui.html)

Comment: I did but I'm still not sure. I haven't used Spark-UI, but from what I understand, I don't think they are repeating. How should duplicate stages look? Same Input, Output, etc., or smth else? And if there are no duplicates, is it possible that it is just a progress bar bug showing twice or it shouldn't happen?

Comment: *To be clear, I meant I haven't used Spark-UI much to understand all the monitoring, but I did check it in this case.